# Facebook PHP SDK "missing OAuth data" exception when retrieving signed request data from tab page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Facebook application that I use on my own web application to interact with a user's account and pages.

Now I'm implementing adding tabs to the user's pages and I'm using separate FB apps for that (because I want multiple tabs on the same page and FB only allows one per app). I am able to add a tab and I see it the link for it on my test page, so that part works.

The trouble starts when I access the tab. The iframe in the tab page makes a POST request to my application, to the correct URL, but when I try to get the information about the page, I get an exception:

```php
exception 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Invalid signed request, missing OAuth data.' in /myprojectpath/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php:343
```

I'm using the latest release of the Facebook PHP SDK at the time of writing (4.0.6) and the code that messes things up is this:

```php
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($my_app_id, $my_app_secret);
$session = FacebookSession::newSessionFromSignedRequest($_POST['signed_request']);
```

I know about this issue: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/issues/14
I'm already using version 4.0.6, though, so that shouldn't be the problem. Besides, my point is exactly that I don't want or need to redirect the user to a login page, because I don't want the user to have to login just to see a page tab.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `newSessionFromSignedRequest` function will only work is the user is already logged into the tab app. You will need to ask the user to login if a session doesn't exist.

Try something like this:

```
// redirect.php should redirect the user back to the Facebook Page
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://yourwebsite.com/redirect.php' );

try {
  // try to get the page session
  $session = FacebookSession::newSessionFromSignedRequest( $_POST['signed_request'] );
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {

  // print logged-in user's ID
  print_r( $session->getSessionInfo()->asArray()['user_id'] );

  // print logout url using session
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://yourwebsite.com/logout.php' ) . '">Logout</a>';

} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends' ) ) . '" target="_top">Login</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Niraj, but the point is I don't want to ask the user to login. What I want to do is allow the owner of the FB page to set up a tab that shows some content via my web application, and then allow anyone to see that content in the page tab. For this use case, I obviously don't want to force users to authenticate against my app. Is this not possible?

Comment: An additional detail: I was creating a session so I could get the signed request data, because I need the page ID (so that my web application knows what content to show). Is there another way to get it without creating a session?

Comment: The SDK doesn't support retrieval of the of the signed_request without logging the user in yet. Facebook said it will be added in the future.